# How do you leave the Hedge?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, changeling-the-lost

How do you get out of the Hedge?

To quote the core rule book:

> To escape the Hedge, a changeling either 
>   needs  to find an active (not necessarily open) gateway, or 
>   find  a  suitable  door,  archway, mirror  or what-have-you  to 
>   make into a gateway.

What is an "active gateway"?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Definitions:**

- *Gateway*: any door/arch/reflective surface; can be opened by spending a point of glamour
- *Active Gateway*: a gateway that has been opened before. Can be reopened, either by spending a point of glamour, or by succeeding a Wyrd roll. Active gateways can be recognised/found from the hedge side (see below) or, if you have the **Hedge Gate Sense** Merit from *Rites of Spring*, from the mortal side as well.
- *Open Gateway*: a gateway that is currently open. A gateway remains open for a number of turns equal to the Wyrd of the opening changeling after it has finished being used.

**Leaving the hedge:**
You may leave the hedge though a Open gateway. This could be an active gateway found with some effort from inside the hedge (Wits + Investigation + Wyrd; see page 218 of *Changeling: The Lost*) which you then must open, either with glamour or a Wyrd roll.

Or it could be a new gateway — a reflective puddle, an arch of thorns, or if you are lucky, the hedge analogue of a door or arch that exists in the real world. If you open a new gateway, then it will dump you out somewhere around where you expect though some exit. (That's assuming you are where you think you are: see "navigating the hedge" on p. 219 of the CtL core.)

Answer (score 7):

Gateways are places that you can move between the Hedge and other "realms", and being active means that it could be used.  A active gateway could be used by anyone that finds their way into the Hedge, where an inactive one might have had its power drained, or possibly require a key.

To use the example of a door:  If it is active, stepping through it would transport the person into the material realm. Alternatively, if it is inactive, stepping through that door would have no special effect.

Comment: your answer is good and helpful.
it's helped me get a understanding of it.
I cam to a fuller understanding after reading your answer plus the section in the book 4 times, and then the section on hollow doors in RoS